# Paypal: How to create recurring profile in payflow

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I need to create recurring profile using payflow. Is there any good library for this which I can use.

I know what parameters I have to pass. But, which method I need to call is confusing me. 
I am new to this. So, I am not getting exactly what I have to do. I have my payflow details. I can login into my manager.paypal.com and I can see its activated. I have used angelleye library. But, there isn't any library for creating recurring profile using PayFlow.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my library to get this done the same you would anything else you do with PayFlow.  Just open up that PayFlow file that's included with my library and adjust the parameters accordingly.

PayPal provides [detailed documentation on recurring billing with PayFlow](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf).  Any parameters that are shown there but aren't included with my library file can simply be added.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Your guideline certainly helped me a lot and I implemented it successfully. You have really built great library.

Comment: Where is your library?